# When starting the gwt:run-codeserver some async classes wont be found

Tags: maven, gwt, m2e

I am trying to start the superdev mode but it does not work. I does not find the Async files. I am starting the with this command

mvn gwt:run-codeserver -Dgwt=de.srs.pen.pdkonsole.HwrEditor

```
[INFO] Compiling module de.srs.pen.pdkonsole.HwrEditor
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 81 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/K:/workspaces/mvn_pdix/HwrEditor/src/main/java/de/srs/pen/pdkonsole/client/HwrEditor.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 35: No source code is available for type de.srs.pen.pdkonsole.client.GreetingServiceAsync; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 37: No source code is available for type de.srs.pen.pdkonsole.client.Messages; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
[INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'de.srs.pen.pdkonsole.client.HwrEditor'
[ERROR]         at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:96)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[ERROR]         at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
[INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its sourcepath entries properly
[ERROR]         at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:87)
[INFO] [ERROR] Compiler returned false
[ERROR]         at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.725s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 06 16:20:40 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/490M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can compile it with mvn gwt:compile and also the dev mode works with mvn gwt:run but I dont understand why superdev is not starting. I have read a lot of stuff concerning this topic but I could not solve it with these tips. Maybe someone here has a a good advice 
thanks.

Comment: Have you disabled async generation in pom file?